# Why doesn't dotnet new on Mac create .csproj files?

Tags: .net, macos, asp.net-core, .net-core

With the .NET Core SDK 1.1 installed in OSX, the `dotnet new` command creates two files:

```
Program.cs
project.json
```

I thought MS was moving toward `csproj`? Is this not the case for non-Windows environments? Is there an announcement I missed somewhere?

Comment: It's not tied to the framework, its tied to the tooling, currently preview3 for VS 2017 preview 2 tools for VS 2015 don't support it yet. So unless you use a build server with msbuild or VS2017 you'll still have to use the old format until VS Code or the Xamarin IDE is updated to handle it

Comment: MS moved to csproj for VS 2017, but not for command line generator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is correct behavior for the **currently available** tooling. This will change soon.

Currently, "classic" .NET Framework projects (on Windows) use `.csproj`, while .NET Core projects use `project.json` (plus `.xproj` when using Visual Studio 2015). When the [final tooling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/) is released, everything will use `.csproj` for consistency across all platforms.

In the current tooling version, `dotnet new` will create the two files you mentioned. When `project.json` is deprecated, you should be able to use `dotnet migrate` to convert it to a `.csproj`.

For now, don't worry about it! .NET Core works great on Mac right now, and will continue to work after the tooling changes.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the website has never been updated. If you want to use csproj on Mac, you need to [download RC4 from the link on the dotnet/cli repository](https://github.com/dotnet/cli#installers-and-binaries). Note that you may need to ctrl+click open the file to get your Mac to allow you to run the installer, because it came from the internet.

Side note: [The latest version of the Yo generator no longer produces project.json, so if you download the latest version of Yo, you'll need to go get RC4 from the project site to use it.](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet/issues/927) That's how I discovered this issue.